# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable, me sale este error en la ecuación y=6+3(pow(x,2))+2(pow(x,2)), no entiendo qué hacer

Tags: python

Estoy intentando hacer un programa usando el metodo de bisección, lo que pasa es que no sé cómo inicializar la función que me dan para dicho programa. La función que me dan es [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], si me pudieran ayudar con ese detalle de cómo expresar la ecuación en python y si el codigo lo tengo bien para calcular las raíces usando el metodo de bisección. De antemano muchas gracias.

## Función para polinomios

```
def poli(x):
    y=6+3(pow(x,2))+2(pow(x,2))
    return (y)

#Toma de valores y acumuladores
xinf= 1
xsup= 2
iter=0
xr= (xinf+xsup)/2
error=1000
es=0.5
imax=30
print("{0:>5s}{1:>22s}{2:>20s}{3:>20s}{4:>20s}{5:>20s}{6:>20s}".format("i","xinf","xsup","xr","signo","cambio","error"))
#Programa principal
while (error >= es) and (iter<imax):
   
    xr= (xinf+xsup)/2
    test= poli(xinf)*poli(xr)
    if test <0:
        xsup=xr
        signo="negativo"
        limite="superior"
    if test >0:
        xinf=xr
        signo="positivo"
        limite="inferior"
    else:
        error=0
    if iter >1:
        error= abs((xr-xrold)/xr)*100
    xrold=xr
    iter=iter+1
    print("{0:>5s}{1:>22s}{2:>20s}{3:>20s}{4:>20s}{5:>20s}{6:>20s}".format(iter, float(xinf), float(xsup), float(xr), signo, limite,(poli(xr))))
print("La raiz es:", xr)
```

Comment: Me parece que tienes un error tipográfico, prueba está formula `6 + (3 * pow(x,2)) + (2 * pow(x,2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te ha faltado el operador de multiplicación en la fórmula que declaras en la función "poli". Al colocar el entero antes del paréntesis, python asume que es estás invocando una función llamada "3" y de ahí el error "int is not callable". Quedaría:

```
def poli(x):
    return 6 + 3 * pow(x,2) + 2 * pow(x,2)
```